# Which distance measurement fits best for features that have very different value ranges?

Tags: python, distance, euclidean-distance, standardized

I have given record with different features. In total I have 8 features. Some are binary, but some have a value range from 0 to 10 million. My big goal is to cluster the data. At the moment I am still looking for a suitable distance measure for these data.

I know the Euclidean distance is the most common distance measure. I have already tried this and normalized the non-binary data for it into the range between 0 and 1. Is there another distance measure that is perhaps more suitable for this data?

Comment: Since you are almost silent on the issue of what your data represents I can unhesitatingly recommend using `log(Euclidean distance)`.

Comment: What is the advantage in comparison to the normal Euclidean distance? Will the problem with the binary features be solved?